# Converting a big amount of if elses to a switch/case for a smaller code

Tags: javascript

Because I have a lot of if else statements for unique id's, I would like to change the code to a switch/case. After doing some research at switches I do understand a bit of it now. Although I cannot get how I should change **this** function to a switch:

```
window.onload = function () {
    function check() {
        if (document.querySelector('#switch-wrapper-1 input').checked) {
            document.querySelector('#switch-wrapper-1 p').textContent = "Disabled";
            $('#card-1').addClass('card-disabled');
        } else {
            document.querySelector('#switch-wrapper-1 p').textContent = "Visible";
            $('#card-1').removeClass('card-disabled');
        }

        if (document.querySelector('#switch-wrapper-2 input').checked) {
            document.querySelector('#switch-wrapper-2 p').textContent = "Disabled";
            $('#card-2').addClass('card-disabled');
        } else {
            document.querySelector('#switch-wrapper-2 p').textContent = "Visible";
            $('#card-2').removeClass('card-disabled');
        }

        if (document.querySelector('#switch-wrapper-3 input').checked) {
            document.querySelector('#switch-wrapper-3 p').textContent = "Disabled";
            $('#card-3').addClass('card-disabled');
        } else {
            document.querySelector('#switch-wrapper-3 p').textContent = "Visible";
            $('#card-3').removeClass('card-disabled');
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('input-1').onchange = check;
    document.getElementById('input-2').onchange = check;
    document.getElementById('input-3').onchange = check;
    check();
}
```

I will try to show my imagination on how to sort of do this so you will understand better what I want:

```
window.onload = function (){
    function check(){
        var switchWrapper = document.querySelector('.switch-wrapper input').checked; // Overall class for all inputs
        switch(scenario){
            case 0: 
            document.getElementById("switch-wrapper-1 input").textContent = "Disabled";
            break;

            case 1: 
            document.getElementById("switch-wrapper-2 input").textContent = "Disabled";
            break;

            case 2: 
            document.getElementById("switch-wrapper-3 input").textContent = "Disabled";
            break;

            default:
            document.getElementsByClassname("switch-wrapper input").textContent = "Enabled";
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('switch-wrapper-1 input').onchange = check;
    document.getElementById('switch-wrapper-2 input').onchange = check;
    document.getElementById('switch-wrapper-3 input').onchange = check;
    check();
}
```

This is definitely not how it should work, but if someone could correct it or make something that works it would be great

I made a fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/4heoz0nd/

Comment: Is only one option  allowed to be checked or is any number allowed?

Comment: Looks there are three different if-else conditions. So I guess its ok to use if-else condition. To use switch cases, there should a if-else ladder.

Comment: Tbh If I understand your idea correctly I don't think it will be better to rewrite it with switch. It would be more appropriate if you had switching for a single value but in your code it will be something like case cond1 && cond2: ; case cond1 && !cond2; case !cond1 && cond2; etc etc. Which will be result in a very messy code.

Comment: All numbers are allowed to be checked, I should also mention that they should all work individually

Comment: if those are radio boxes then they have to use if / else statements, you could use switch only for checkboxes

Comment: I believe in @SamuilPetrov's answers best, I think I'll stick with the if else then. I understand those better too tho.

Comment: You can use Wildcards in Selector:
`document.querySelectorAll([id^='switch-wrapper-'])'

please make a fiddle. I think you don´t need if or switch...

Comment: @FrankWisniewski I made a JSfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/4heoz0nd/

Comment: Thank you i  post an answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this fiddle [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e5brLhyy/)

you need no jQuery.

only this lttle script before the closing body tag:

```
        Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[id^="switch-wrapper-"] input[type=checkbox]')).forEach(function(elem){
            elem.onchange=function(){
                this.parentNode.querySelector('p').innerHTML = (this.checked) ? 'Disabled' : "Visible";
                //when you have mor than 9 cards take the number with an regex..
                var newSel = '#card-'+ this.id[6];
                document.querySelector(newSel).classList.toggle('card-disabled');
            }
        });
```

Comment: Damn! That's impressive! Can't thank you enough for your answer! Marking as the right answer!

Comment: Can I ask you one more thing? If a checkbox is already checked before load, like so: <input type="checkbox" id="input-1" class="display-none" checked="checked"> The javascript is not reacting on that, how can I make that work? I tried using window.onload but that didn't work

Comment: you must init ...

`Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[id^="switch-wrapper-"] input[type=checkbox]')).forEach(function(elem){
      elem.parentNode.querySelector('p').innerHTML = (elem.checked) ? 'Disabled' : "Visible";
      console.log(elem.id[6]);
      if (elem.checked)document.querySelector('#card-'+ elem.id[6]).classList.add("card-disabled");
     });`

Comment: Yes! Thanks again, now I won't bother you anymore :')

Comment: No Problem...We are country neighbors ;-)